# occurred evaluating root project > plugin with com.android.application not found

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Downloaded an android project having a problem I have this in a gradle file...

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.5'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

But I am getting the error..

`Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found`

Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: Can you post the top-level gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

try in root gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
  dependencies {
    // 2.1.2 is newest  plugin but required studio >=  2.1
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0' 
    // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
    // quickly to Android tooling updates
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

in app or lib gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//Put Fabric plugin after Android plugin
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

for fabric version plugin see:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/fabric-artifacts/repo/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml

```
<latest>1.21.5</latest>
<release>1.21.6</release>
```

btw don't use  plus sign in libs/classes  it's slows down the build process:  instead **classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'**  use ->  **classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.6'**